# What settings are needed to ensure the communication of the cluster in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What protocol and how does the cluster communication perform in Apache IoTDB? Seems like there's no password-free settings needed for communicating in cluster, so I want to know what settings are needed to ensure the communication? Does the synchronization of data copies between clusters also do not need to be password-free?

Answer (score 0):

The communication of the cluster in Apache IoTDB is ensured by RPC. Therefore, as long as the server's network port is open and be able to connect, the communication will be fine. Password-free that you are asking is mainly used to copy files between servers.